# wrong enqueue script order in wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue my script in a child theme in wordpress, but i get it loaded before Jquery even though I've specified Jquery dependency.

The code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_scripts' );
function child_theme_scripts(){    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-menu-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dynamic-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

no matter what I do (I tried registering first, then specifying my script in the array after jquery, i tried to specify to load the script in the footer, i tried to enqueue JQuery externally) my script loads before query throwing me a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: JQuery" I've checked JQ is loading properly but after my script.

this thing is driving me crazy, please help me...

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery dependency is not being changed to another handle in your parent theme?

Comment: this is a sample enqueue from parent theme
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-methods', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/methods.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can improve the order of scripts loading with priority parameter. Default priority is 10, so you may set it to 11.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_scripts', 11 );
```

Here's a simple helper function that shows you what functions are assigned to the hook you want to use.

```
function print_filters_for( $hook = '' ) {
  global $wp_filter;
  if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) )
    return;

  print '<pre>';
  print_r( $wp_filter[$hook] );
  print '</pre>';
}
```

you can call it anywhere in templates with `print_filters_for( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );`

Comment: This is such a perfect solution! but still doesn't work, at this point there must be something wrong in the parent theme I suppose...

Comment: Perhaps you can give us the output of the HTML?

Comment: OK I checked it was perhaps a cache problem now it works! thanks!

Comment: I also forced the script to load on footer rather than header

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sirBlond,
In my case the `hook = ''` did not work.

I changed it to:

```
function print_filters_for($hook)
```